# Graphics Driver and Resolutions

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, display-resolution

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04, and I have installed 20.04 before. Both of them are unable to work correctly with my graphics driver. They only show up two low screen resolutions.
I tried to add screen resolution. With Ubuntu 21.04 using WAYLAND, I switched back to Ubuntu with Xorg, and add new resolution: 1366x768. With Ubuntu 20.04, I did the same thing. But after adding new resolution, my screen is still blur, so I think that there was some problems with my Intel graphics driver.
I'm using Intel Pentium G3450. Maybe it's too old for Intel Drivers?
[Screenshot in my settings that might provides some info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwGQu.png)

At once, it suddenly appears two new resolutions, one of them are my desire one: 1366x768 after I restart my computer, so I don't know if it was my driver or something else. But when I restarted again, they disappeared and I came back to blur screen with only two resolutions

I'm new user, so if you need any other information, I'll try to update this question as soon as possible.

Comment: The screenshot you've posted looks very clear. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: I don't know, honestly. It suddenly switch back to my desired screen mode,and after I logout, or restart several times, it'll change back to blur screen. If I couldn't figure out why and fix it, maybe it's best to switch back to Windows.